# I need to split a column up into 3 different parts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that is returned that is one string split up by hyphens.

I need to split this into 2 different columns to represent 'type' and 'hostname'

2 examples of my current column would be -

```
  Wordhere - Drive Space Low - HOSTNAMEHERE - Failure

  Wordhere - Drive Space Low - Server- HOSTNAMEHERE - Failure
```

I have tried numerous different combinations of SUBSTRING to no avail, so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

So the columns I need to pull from the above examples are type, being the sections 'Drive Space Low' and 'Drive Space Low - Server', and then hostname which is the 'HOSTNAME' section.

If it helps, the column name that these currently live in is 'Service'.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Are you aware about [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? What have you tried so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: Always share sample input  and desired o/p sample with your query.

Comment: So you have a hyphen delimited string but sometimes the string contains a hyphen? Is it possible to fix the data structure so that this is not stored in a single column? How do you know that one row has the hyphen in this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple XML approach would work here. This solution will isolate values from a delimited string and works across SQL versions the solution handles your inconsistent drive space low - server problem:

```
 SELECT
 col1 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(replace([Service],'Drive Space Low - ','Drive Space Low '),'-','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[2]','varchar(100)'),
 col2 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(replace([Service],'Drive Space Low - ','Drive Space Low '),'-','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
 FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING_SPLIT if you are using SQL2016 and above

```
SELECT value
FROM HostInfo
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(HOSTDETAIL, '-')
GO
```

Comment: This is a decent attempt but the OP stated that one of the values contains a hyphen which means this wouldn't work quite right. They also stated they only want two of the delimited values.

Answer (score 1):

The string you're searching for contains hyphens so you could instead extract the portions between first and second last hyphen, and between second last and last one:

```
WITH tests(str) AS (
    SELECT 'Wordhere - Drive Space Low - HOSTNAMEHERE - Failure' UNION
    SELECT 'Wordhere - Drive Space Low - Server - HOSTNAMEHERE - Failure'
)
SELECT str
     , SUBSTRING(str, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1) AS Message
     , SUBSTRING(str, pos2 + 1, pos3 - pos2 - 1) AS Hostname
FROM tests
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CHARINDEX('-', str) AS pos1
         , LEN(str) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(str)) + 1 AS pos3
         , LEN(str) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(str), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(str)) + 1) + 1 AS pos2
) AS ca
```